# Matlab Type structures in python

Tags: python, matlab, structure

Is there any way to implement the following matlab code in python?

```
% Initialization 
savedT2(N) = struct(); minValerr(M) = struct(); %M, N are sizes
% Looping  
for lib0=1:M
    for lib1=1:N  
        %doSeveralThings()  
        savedT2(lib1).filed1 = resultWithNOperations  
        save savedT2 savedT2  
    end  
    minValerr(lib0).field2 = savedT2;  
    save minValerr minValerr  
end
```

I used the following 'ctype' structure definition style in python:

```
class savedT2(Structure):  
    # structure to be called within functional operations  
    _fields_ = [("field1", c_int)]
```

And the second structure definition becomes:

```
class minValerr(Structure):  
    # structure to be called within functional operations with fields: field2  
    _fields_ = [("field2", c_int)]
```

Similar to the Matlab code, we have that:

```
rec0 = savedT2(); rec1 = minValerr  
for k in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        doSomething()
        rec0[j].field1= resultsDoSoemthin
#Assigning 
    rec1[k].field2 = rec0
```

But this method doesn't work. I want to avoid using lists, dictionaries and similar containers (except using them will be the only option available); since the operation has to be performed over 100 000 times. Besides, I will also want to pass a structure with several fields to many python functions, after continuously updating them with new fields not defined earlier. Is there an optimal way to implement the above matlab code in python?

Comment: MATLAB has an [API for Python](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html). You can call MATLAB-Code directly from Python, but structures are returned as dictionaries... There is the function `setattr` in Python. You can take a string and attach a method or attribute to a given object in order to keep the dot-operator... By the way, why do your structures have only one field? Does this relate to your pseudo code example or is it the same in your application?

Comment: Have you tried using dictionaries and were they actually too slow?

Comment: Thanks @nekomatic. I might consider using dicts if there is not other option.

Comment: @Sven Krüger: Thanks, nesting these structures will naturally include new fields. But the above code snippets are used as examples.

Comment: What does actually not work with subclass of `Structure`? What is the error message? What does `rec0` actually look like? Maybe it is not a `list` of `Structure`. In Python you cannot assign like in MATLAB by typing `X[i] = 'value'` if `X` was not defined to have at least `i-1` elements. By the way your intendation might be faulty. The assignment of `rec0[j] = ...` in your example will always be on the index `j = N-1`. Same for `rec1[k]`.

Comment: rec0 is meant to be an object of the 'ctype' structure  class. Thanks, I formatted the indentation; wanted to find out whether the Matlab type Structure can be easily defined in python. There seem to be a similar structure definition in the 'scipy.io' package/module. But one might need to save such structures before loading them for use in a program. @Sven

Answer (score -1):

MATLAB can automatically translate its code to C/C++, and you can find these functions in ‘MATLAB Coder’. Then, reuse them in Python.